# Insufficient privileges using Azure CLI over Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cli2

I try to create a Azure AD Subscription via Azure CLI in Azure Pipeline with following command:

```
        - task: AzureCLI@2
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'SubscriptionName'
            scriptType: 'ps'
            scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
            inlineScript: |
              $appName = "myApp$(randomString)"
              # Create the app registration and get the appId
              $app = az ad app create --display-name $appName --query "appId" -o tsv
```

But after:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account set --subscription XXXXXXX"
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscriptXXXXX.ps1'"
```

I get following error:
Insufficient privileges

The Pipeline has ARM privileges.

[Pipeline Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8rb2.png)

[YML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tJb8.png)

Comment: add another line in you script to update the execution policy of powershell to unrestricted. refer to documentation for information about [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.3) in powershell

Comment: @VenkateshDodda It is already set here: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscriptXXXXX.ps1'"

Comment: I tried adding "Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted". 
didn't work, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Powershell [ps] as a Script type and running Azure CLI bash command which is causing this error, Use below YAML script with Script Type set to bash. And in your Azure Service Connection > Use Service Connection with Application Administrator or Global Administrator or Privileged Administrator role assigned at the Azure AD level. Refer below:-

**My YAML script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az ad app create --display-name appName --query "appId" -o tsv'
```

**scriptType is set to bash** with ***azureSubscription with correct role assigned at Azure Ad level***.

**Output:-**

[image]

My PowershellSid > Service connection in Azure DevOps below:-

[image]

The Service Principal used to create above Service connection in Azure DevOps has below Azure AD role assigned:-

[image]

**Reference Azure Ad roles:-**

[Microsoft Entra built-in roles | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/permissions-reference)

Comment: I used the same script as you and changed it from ps to bash and checked if my ServiceConnection has Cloud Application Admin. But I get the same error message: ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Comment: I added two pictures above to visualize.

Comment: Try adding the same service connection > Global Administrator role at Azure AD level. And also, Owner role at the Subscription level RBAC - https://i.imgur.com/oliZcKz.png. Also, It takes some time for the role to populate from the back end so try to run the pipeline after some time

Comment: The service connection is set to "contributor", maybe thats why. I try to contact my admin and send a answer asap.

Comment: I have tested SiddheshDesai's suggestion. After assigning the service principle with Subscription owner role and AAD global admin role, I can create the app successfully.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT Is this least privileges? 
Global Admin is difficult to communicate internally.